# Query to retrieve certain files from Product2

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have the following use case:

A web shop (Java) retrieving products from SF using the SOAP API. Attached "Files" are retrieved and displayed by selecting them through ContentDocumentLinks related to the Product2 object.

```
SELECT Id, Name, ProductCode, Description, IsActive, 
(SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId FROM Product2.ContentDocumentLinks), 
(SELECT UnitPrice FROM Product2.PriceBookEntries LIMIT 1) 
FROM Product2 WHERE IsActive = true
```

This works, but not all files should be accessible in the web shop. I want to differentiate 3 types of files: `Internal`, `Members only` and `Public`. Our users are not "Salesforce" users (we retrieve data using one API user), so don't think sharing rules or groups can be used...

Best would be if I could change my subquery to: `(SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId FROM Product2.ContentDocumentLinks WHERE Type__c = 'Public')` but I can't add fields to the ContentDocumentLink...

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try leveraging the ContentDocument object? these can be placed in libraries (internal, Members Only, Public) and you can filter on `Product2.ContentDocumentLinks where ContentDocument.Parent.Name = 'Public'`

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for using sharing rules if possible. If that is not an option, because the API user you are using needs access to more links than you want to render, then...

You could create a custom field on the Content version and filter it by the latest version.

```
(SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId FROM Product2.ContentDocumentLinks WHERE ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Type__c = 'Public')
```